# Email alerts about RAID hard disk errors from HPE ProLiant server with iLO

Tags: vmware-esxi, hard-drive, hp-proliant, hpe, alerting

I am looking for a way to get email alerts about possible RAID hard disk failures from the HPE ProLiant server running the free version of ESXi.

Has anyone used iLO successfully for this with the advanced license or even with standard version some way?

I am thinking "Email-based alerting" would most likely be the feature included in the advanced license mentioned in this chart below that could be used for sending these kind of alerts directly to email.

https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c05269613

Would be glad however if someone could confirm whether an advanced license is needed for these kinds of alerts or is there a way to set up that with an unlicensed iLO or standard version.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a [trial Advanced license](https://www.hpe.com/us/en/resources/integrated-systems/ilo-advanced-trial.html) for the ILO.

But yes, this feature can be used to send email alerts to an SMTP server.

Comment: Is this "iLO AlertMail" actually same feature as "email based alerting"?
https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=a00045583en_us&docLocale=en_US#N10062